# kubernetes init containers using a private repo

Tags: kubernetes

has anyone tried having the image for an init container in a private repo when using the imagePullSecret to access the registry?  Below is a sample for a private registry with image pull secrets.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
   containers:
     - name: private-reg-container
       image: privatereg:5000/private-image-name
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regsecret
```

When you define the init containers, the secrets cannot be included with the init-container since its not part of the container spec.

So will it still work using init containers?  I see in the example https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/ that they have a volume created in the spec and its available in the init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it via annotations:

```
annotations:
  pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[
    {
      "name": "install",
       "image": "my-init-container",
       "imagePullSecrets": "something"
     }
    ]'
```

Comment: Hi...where should we put this annotation? I tried adding in the template spec but it gave me an invalid deployment error.

Comment: unfortunately this answer is 6 years old. Init containers are now a part of the deployment spec

Comment: yes no need to add via annotations.ImagePullSecret via Pod spec works for initContainers.