# Using kubernetes init containers on a private repo

Tags: kubernetes

I've been trying to run a deployment using a private init container image with little success, I always get this error:

```
Failed to pull image "private/app": Error: image private/app:latest not found
Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "app" with ErrImagePull: "Error: image private/app:latest not found"
```

Here is my deployment:

```
"kind": "Deployment"
"apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1"
"metadata":
  "name": "tomcat"
  "creationTimestamp": null
"spec":
  "replicas": 1
  "template":
    "metadata":
      "creationTimestamp": null
      "labels":
        "service": "tomcat"
      "annotations":
        "pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers": '[
          {
            "name": "app",
            "image": "private/app",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ]'
    "spec":
      "containers":
        - "name": "tomcat"
          "image": "private/tomcat"
          "ports":
            - "containerPort": 8080
              "protocol": "TCP"
      "imagePullSecrets":
        - "name": "my-secret"
      "restartPolicy": "Always"
  "strategy": {}
"status": {}
```

I also tried it with the change suggested here [kubernetes init containers using a private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422892/kubernetes-init-containers-using-a-private-repo):

```
"pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers": '[
  {
    "name": "app",
    "image": "private/app",
    "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
    "imagePullSecrets": [
      {
        "name": "my-secret"
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

But still nothing...

Note that I have tested this deployment without the init container and the image pulling was successful.

Also note that this is a simplified version of my actual configuration, in the real configuration there is volume mounting for both containers and some env variables.

How do I configure "imagePullSecrets" for an init-container?

**Edit:**
I was asking around in the kubernetes slack channel and it seems I forgot to give permissions to the cluster docker user (CI docker user if you would) permissions to this hub repository, once I did that the "imagePullPolicy" on the init container was redundant, the one on the "template" > "spec" was enough.

Thanks @koki, wherever you might be.

Answer (score 1):

You should using `secret` object.

something like this:

```
  kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistry \
  --docker-server=https://example.io \
  --docker-username=foo \
  --docker-password=boosecret \
  --docker-email=example@boo.com
```

And use it , in another object like this:

```
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: myregistry
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been trying to use "imagePullSecrets" in my deployment, it works for the containers described under the "spec" section, but not for the init-containers in the "annotations" section.

Also the "imagePullSecrets" property accepts an **array** of "LocalObjectReference" as described here:
[link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_podspec)
and not an **object**.

Comment: @AviFarada any updates on how you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

so i was the one who asked that other question you referenced. this is using your example what my init section looks like. and this does not work for you?

```
   "pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers": '[
  {
    "name": "app",
    "image": "private/app",
    "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
    "imagePullSecrets": "my-secret"
  }
]'
```

Comment: I edited my question with the solution to my problem, thanks for the answer!