# how to git clone from a private github repo in an kubernetes init container

Tags: git, github, kubernetes, ssh

It is possible, through either https or ssh to clone from a private repo **without creating a secrets file with my git credentials?** I don't see why this is recommended, anyone in the kubernetes cluster can view my git credentials if they wanted to...

Both of the top two answers advocate this dangerously unsafe practice
[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422892/kubernetes-init-containers-using-a-private-repo) and [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462244/using-kubernetes-init-containers-on-a-private-repo).

I've also been looking at git-sync but it also wants to expose the git credentials to everyone in the cluster [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462244/using-kubernetes-init-containers-on-a-private-repo).

Is it assumed that you'd have a service account for this? What if I don't have a service account? Am I just out of luck?

Comment: Can you pass environment variables with your credentials into the container?  If so, there are ways to do this.

Comment: the issue is that it's a shared environment, so someone could exec into the container and list the env

Comment: If there's no way to get secrets into the container without others being able to read them, then there is no secure way to do this.  If you just want to clone from a repository that everyone in the cluster should intrinsically have access to, then you could use a deploy key, which will restrict access to a single repo.

Comment: Create a personal access token in github and grant only relevant permission to the token to pull the repo. Use it in your init container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credentials have to exist somewhere and a Secret is the best place for them. You wouldn't give access to "anyone" though, you should use the Kubernetes RBAC policy system to limit access to Secret objects to only places and people that need them. There are other solutions which read directly from some other database (Hashicorp Vault, AWS SSM, GCP SM, etc) but they are generally the same in terms of access control since the pod would be authenticating to that other system using its ServiceAccount token which ... is in a Secret. If you go full-out on this I'm sure you can find some kind of HSM which supports GitHub but unless you have a lot of hundreds of thousands of dollars to burn, that seems like overkill vs. just writing a better RBAC policy.