# add imagepullsecret to init-containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am trying to use init-containers with image from private registry. I added imagePullSecret in template spec annotations ( and also in pod spec and job spec) but it is not working.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubernetes init containers using a private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422892/kubernetes-init-containers-using-a-private-repo)

Comment: Thank You DazWilkin for answering but I wanted to know where we can put the annotation as I tried it in the template and pod spec but got an error.

Comment: As suggested by the above comment you need to add Annotations above imagePullSecrets; and also please check whether your kubernetes cluster has the access to pull the image.

Comment: Hi Abhijit...can you share an example, please.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting below example from the Annotations [Document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/); please go through this document for further reference:

> apiVersion: v1
>
> ```
> kind: Pod
>
> metadata:
>
>  name: annotations-demo
>
>  annotations:### Add here###
>
>  pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[
> {
>  "name": "install",
>  "image": "my-init-container",
>  "imagePullSecrets": "something"
>  }
>
> ]'
>
>    imagePullSecrets: -name: <secret-name>
>
>
> spec:
>
>  containers:
>
>  - name: nginx
>
>    image: nginx:1.14.2
>
>    ports:
>
>    - containerPort: 80
> ```

Please make necessary changes as per your requirements

Comment: imagerPullSecret via annotations does not work in new version. It had to be added via Pod Spec.